# Spring cloud : Angel.SR6 to Brixton.M5 : configuration issue

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I migrated Spring cloud from Angel.SR6 to Brixton.M5 and I have a properties issue about EurekaInstanceConfigBean.

Indeed, the following properties are not take in account in the last version (Brixton.M5):

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    preferIpAddress: true
```

I need the last one to deploy my project on Docker.

Comment: You haven't explained what happens, can you please do that?

Comment: Also, try with RC1 as it's the latest version.

Comment: I have the same problem with RC1 version. My hostname and preferIpAddress properties are ignored during the eureka registration.

Comment: You'll have to tell me more about what is happening. Is that configuration in `application.yml` or `bootstrap.yml`? What do you mean they 'are ignored'. You've given so little information I can't even make a guess.